# Helm delete and reinstall deployment. Wait or not to wait?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pvc

I have situation where I am deploying some chart, let's call it "myChart".

Let's suppose I have a pipeline, where I am doing below:

```
helm delete myChart_1.2 -n <myNamespace>
```

An **right after** I am installing new one:

```
helm delete myChart_1.3 -n <myNamespace>
```

Does Kubernetes or maybe Helm knows that all the resources should be deleted first and then install new?

For instance there might be some PVC and PV that are still not deleted. Is there any problem with that, should I add some waits before deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helm delete (aka. uninstall) should remove the objects managed in a given deployment, before exiting.

Still, when the command returns: you could be left with resources in a Terminating state, pending actual deletion.

Usually, we could find about PVC, that may still be attached to a running container.

Or objects such as ReplicaSet or Pods -- most likely, your Helm chart installs Deployments, DaemonSets, StatefulSets, ... top-level objects may appear to be deleted, while their child objects are still being terminated.

Although this shouldn't be an issue for Helm, assuming that your application is installed using a generated name, and as long as your chart is able to create multiple instances of a same application, in a same cluster/namespace, ... without them overlapping ( => if all resources managed through Helm have unique names, which is not always the case ).

If your chart is hosted on a public repository, let us know what to check. And if you're not one of the maintainer for that chart: beware that Helm charts could go from amazing to very bad, depending on who's contributing, what use cases have been met so far, ...

Comment: Let's suppose that name of the resource is the same, it is not generated.

What I observed that some of the "old" pvc's are stuck in terminate. The assumption was that it happens due to the use case described above. Can it be true?

Comment: Could be. If there's a Pod that is stuck in a terminating state (maybe in relation with some terminationgraceperiodseconds -- default: 30 seconds), the PVC that are attached to it would not be purged until that Pod is terminated. In the meantime, you can't re-create a PVC with that name.

Answer (score 1):

**Kubernetes (and Helm by extension) will never clean up PVCs that have been created as part of StatefulSets.** This is intentional (see relevant [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/delete-stateful-set/#persistent-volumes)) to avoid accidental loss of data.

Therefore, if you do have PVCs created from StatefulSets in your chart and if your pipeline re-installs your Helm chart under the same name, ensure that PVCs are deleted explicitly after running "helm delete", e.g. with a separate "kubectl delete" command.